# Confusion on a couple of paragraphs on equivalence principles

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, equivalence-principle

I'm reading Carroll's GR book. I'm able to follow it for the most part, but a couple of paragraphs are a bit hard to decipher:

> According to the WEP, the gravitational mass of the hydrogen atom is therefore less than the sum of the masses of its constituents; the gravitational field **couples to** electromagnetism (which holds the atom together) in exactly the right way to make the gravitational mass come out right.

What exactly does "couples to" mean? Right now that's just a vague phrase to me that implies gravitational field has something to do with EM - but what's the precise notion behind it?

> Sometimes a distinction is drawn between "gravitational laws of physics" and
> "nongravitational laws of physics," and the EEP is defined to apply only to the
> latter. Then the Strong Equivalence Principle (SEP) is defined to include all of the
> laws of physics, gravitational and otherwise. **A theory that violated the SEP but
> not the EEP would be one in which the gravitational binding energy did not contribute
> equally to the inertial and gravitational mass of a body; thus, for example,
> test particles with appreciable self-gravity (to the extent that such a concept makes
> sense) could fall along different trajectories than lighter particles**.

I have no idea what the statement in bold means at all. Could anyone please explain this so that a layman like me could understand?